# Mapbox gl JS popup : forcing to display popup on the opposite side

Tags: popup, mapbox-gl-js

on mapbox gl JS ,  is it possible to configure the popup to make is appear on the opoosite side of the computed position
Im the screenshot,  mapbox make the popup appear at the position (in green)   but I want to force it to appear the opposite side , in RED

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`anchor`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup) property controls:

> A string indicating the part of the Popup that should be positioned closest to the coordinate set via Popup#setLngLat . Options are 'center' , 'top' , 'bottom' , 'left' , 'right' , 'top-left' , 'top-right' , 'bottom-left' , and 'bottom-right' . If unset the anchor will be dynamically set to ensure the popup falls within the map container with a preference for 'bottom' .